# SwiftUI sharing timer through views in navigation view

Tags: swiftui, timer, navigationview

I'm pretty new at SwiftUI.
I would like to make an app that navigates through different views in a Navigation View and running a timer in background presenting the time on each of the views.
The problem is when I navigate to a second level of navigation. When the timer is on, the app returns automatically to the previous navigation view.
Here's is a screenshot video of what I mean:
https://youtu.be/eXbK9jpluvk

Here is my code:

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

```
@State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1,  on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
@State var seconds : Int = 0
@State var paused : Bool = true

var body: some View {
    
    
    VStack {
        Text("\(seconds)")
        Button(action: {
            paused.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: paused ? "play.fill" : "stop.fill")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: FirstView( timerSeconds: $seconds, timerPaused: $paused)) {
            Text("Navigate 1")
        }.padding()
    }
    .onReceive(self.timer) { currentTime in
        if !paused {
            seconds = seconds + 1
            print(currentTime)
        }
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    
}
```

}

struct FirstView: View {

```
@Binding var timerSeconds : Int
@Binding var timerPaused : Bool

var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Text("First View")
            Text("\(timerSeconds)")
            Button(action: {
                timerPaused.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: timerPaused ? "play.fill" : "stop.fill")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(seconds: $timerSeconds)) {
                Text("Navigate 2")
            }
        }
    
}
```

}

struct SecondView: View {

```
@Binding var seconds : Int

var body: some View {
    Text("\(seconds)")
}
```

}

Any help will be welcome!!
Thanks a lot

Comment: Your code works fine with me. You're just missing a `NavigationView` in `ContentView`, but maybe you have it on a higher level. – or do you want the time individually on each view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavigationView` can only push on one detail `NavigationLink` so to have more levels you need to set [`.isDetailLink(false)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationviewstyle/stack) on the link. Alternatively, if you don't expect to run in landscape split view, you could set [`.navigationViewStyle(.stack)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationviewstyle/stack) on the navigation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about `.isDetailLink(false)`. That made it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `.isDetailLink(false)` didn't solve the issue, but I found another solution. Want to post in case someone would look for a similar case.

I had a button with timer that leads to the multilevel navigation. To solve the issue I moved the timer updates from higher-vew level to the level of button itself.

```
struct LinkSentView: View {
    
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: LinkSentViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: LinkSentViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            NavigationLink(destination: nameDestination(), isActive: $viewModel.fakeTrigger) { EmptyView() }
                .isDetailLink(false)
        ResendTimerButtonView(viewModel: ResendTimerButtonViewModel(resendLinkAction: viewModel.resendLink))
    enter code here
    }

class ResendTimerButtonViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private static let timeLimit = 30
    @Published private var timer: Timer?
    @Published private var timeRemaining = ResendTimerButtonViewModel.timeLimit
    
    var resendButtonText: String {
        timeRemaining > 0 ? "\(timeRemaining)s \(LinkSentView.Constant.resendButtonTitle)" : "\(LinkSentView.Constant.resendButtonTitle)"
    }
    
    var resendLinkAction: () -> ()
    
    init(resendLinkAction: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.resendLinkAction = resendLinkAction
    }
    
    func startTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {[weak self] tempTimer in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
                self.timeRemaining -= 1
            } else {
                tempTimer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func resendLink() {

    }
}

struct ResendTimerButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ResendTimerButtonViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Button(title: viewModel.resendButtonText, action: {
            viewModel.resendLink()
        })
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.startTimer()
        }
    }
}
```